# Set text in the centre of AppBar

Tags: android, appbar

I this is my xml:

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appbar"
        android:layout_height="57dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:text="Ranger"
            android:id="@+id/logoSign"/>
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

I want to do the TextView in the centre of the AppBar. But I get this:
[image]

Thanks for your help. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

just use this code for textview

```
<TextView
        android:layout_width="match_content"
        android:layout_height="match_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Ranger"
        android:id="@+id/logoSign"/>
```

Answer (score 2):

`AppBar` is actually a `Linearlayout`.
Try this:

```
   <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Ranger"
        android:id="@+id/logoSign"/>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/appbar"
    android:layout_height="57dp"
    android:layout_width="match_parent">
    <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:gravity="center">
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Ranger"
            android:id="@+id/logoSign"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

What you can do is Take a RelativeLayout inside the AppBar with height and width as "match_parent" and put the TextView inside the RelativeLayout and make it as

```
android:layout_centerInParent="true"
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
        android:text="Ranger"
        android:id="@+id/logoSign"/>
```